# can't set cookie name

Tags: php, session-cookies

I'm having a problem to set the cookie name, i decided to post the methods here.

In my Main page i call the following methods:

```
 $CHAT->login($_POST['cliente']);
 $CHAT->entraFila();
```

The methods are:

```
public function login($cli, $senha){
     $this->cliente = $cli;
 }

 public function entraFila(){
    $fila_id = $this->DB->criaFila($this->cliente);
    if($fila_id){
         // -------------------------------- SETING THE COOKIE BELOW    <<<<< ---       
         setcookie("CHAT_FILA_ID", $fila_id, time() + 86400); 
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
 }
```

The "entraFila" method call "criaFila" method in another class:

```
 public function criaFila($cli){
    $insert = sprintf("INSERT INTO filas (cliente, data) VALUES (%s, NOW())", 
            GETSQLValueString($cli, "text")
    );
    $query = mysql_query($insert) or die(mysql_error());
    if($query){
        return mysql_insert_id($query);
    } else {
        return $query;
    }
 }
```

When i'm check the cookie in another pages, it always return false:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_COOKIE['CHAT_FILA_ID'])){
    // CONDITION ALWAYS ENTER HERE
    header("location: login.php");
}
```

In the chrome, i checked the name of the cookie, and it's setted like "PHPSESSID"

What's wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you already started your output when calling `setcookie()` in that case the cookie won't be set. Try running your `setcookie()` at the top of the page.

Comment: Make sure to make different requests for setting and for checking. When you set a cookie in your code, you can't directly check if it's set in the next line, but have to 'refresh' the page first. Also, make sure that setting the cookie is the first thing you do (with absolutely no output before, like blank spaces or something).

Comment: Do you get value of $fila_id every time ?

Comment: Read the manual for `setcookie()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: I'm checking the cookie in different pages.

Comment: @Milap         I'm insert values in mysql and i set $fila_id with the mysql_insert_id.

Comment: Is there any case when value of $fila_id will be null ?

Comment: No, i'm check if($fila_id) before set the cookie

Comment: I edited the code to best comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

If you call setcookie after you have anything on the output your cookie will not set and if you have turned off error reporting you will not get any warning about this issue.

Other thing:
Even is your setcookie() call is successful you will not have that cookie in your $_COOKIE array just after one new request.

No you don't have to start a session to use cookies.